# What is happening behind an evaluation of Sort with meaningless order-function?

Tags: sorting

If we try `Sort[]` with meaningless order-function like

```
Sort[{3, 2, 1}, True]
```

or,

```
Sort[{3, 2, 1}, False]
```

gives `{3, 2, 1}`, i.e., `Sort[]` does not do anything.

For the former case, I think it is natural because every comparison of two elements returns `True`, but what about the latter case?

I tried the visualization shown in the Wolfram document for `Sort[]`, but I cannot understand why the sort converges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `True` and `False` are not functions, they are just symbols. To demonstrate, evaluate

```
True[3, 2]
```

You should get back just `True[3, 2]` unevaluated. You can easily create a constant function, however, by just tacking on `&`:

```
True &[3, 2]
```

This time you should get back `True`.

So, in your original attempt, since you didn't get an actual boolean result for each comparison, no change was made. To force a constant comparison function, you could try these:

```
Sort[{3, 2, 1}, True &] (* {3, 2, 1} *)
Sort[{3, 2, 1}, False &] (* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my question. Sorry for the fundamental mistake of me. Thank you very much!